# search filter check wrong checkbox Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I have problems with search filter and checkboxs.

I have list of checkbox with colors (pantons) ex.: **"green, yellow, blue, red, pink, orange, black"** and input with search.
And when I write in the input "**bl**", color which are display are "**blue**" and "**black**". And then I have check them and click to save and in the database I had saved "**green**" and "**yellow**" (the 2 first colors on list).

And second problem is when I choose this colors and clear by backspace then the checked checkboxes are unchecked.

What I need to do to the colors right colors will added to database?

Added "checked" to the ng-model of chceckbox is not working.

Plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WOpGTggIigWScTT6LiJ8?p=preview).

My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="flat-panel">
            <div class="flat-panel-header">
                <h3 class="page-header">Choose color</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="nazwaRysunku">Search:  </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="search.nazwa_pan" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <br>
            <div class="flat-panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" >
                    <div class="p-pantony" >
                        <label ng-repeat="panton in pPantons | filter : search track by $index" class="checkbox-inline" style="width: 170px; float: left; border-bottom: 10px solid rgb({{panton.R}},{{panton.G}},{{panton.B}}); margin:0 13px 13px 0;">
                            <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="article.pan[panton.nazwa_pan]" name="pantons" ng-true-value="' {{panton.nazwa_pan}}'" ng-false-value="'x'" > {{panton.nazwa_pan}} 

                        </label>
                         <label ng-repeat="panton in pgPantons | filter : search track by $index" class="checkbox-inline" style="width: 170px; float: left; border-bottom: 10px solid rgb({{panton.R}},{{panton.G}},{{panton.B}}); margin:0 13px 13px 0;">
                            <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="article.pan[panton.nazwa_pan]" name="pantons" ng-true-value="' {{panton.nazwa_pan}}'" ng-false-value="'x'" > {{panton.nazwa_pan}} 

                        </label>
                         <label ng-repeat="panton in innePantons | filter : search track by $index" class="checkbox-inline" style="width: 170px; float: left; border-bottom: 10px solid rgb({{panton.R}},{{panton.G}},{{panton.B}}); margin:0 13px 13px 0;">
                            <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="article.pan[panton.nazwa_pan]" name="pantons" ng-true-value="' {{panton.nazwa_pan}}'" ng-false-value="'x'" > {{panton.nazwa_pan}} 

                        </label>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>    
            </div> <!-- .flat-panel-body -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

Controllers:

```
appPokayoke.controller('CreateArticleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','pantons','$routeParams', 'articles', '$timeout', '$location', '$filter', function ($scope, $http, pantons, $routeParams, articles, $timeout, $location, $filter, rangeFilter) {


        var drawingId = $routeParams.drawingId;
        var pyNumber = $routeParams.pyNumber;
        var divOne = $routeParams.divOne;
        var divTwo = $routeParams.divTwo;
        var divThree = $routeParams.divThree;

        $scope.pyNumber = $routeParams.pyNumber;
        $scope.date = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy');

        $scope.article = {
            "id_rys" : drawingId,
            "data_art" : $scope.date
        }; 


        pantons.getPPantons(function (pPantons) {
            $scope.pPantons = pPantons;            
        });

        pantons.getPgPantons(function (pgPantons) {
            $scope.pgPantons = pgPantons;
        });

        pantons.getInnePantons(function (innePantons) {
            $scope.innePantons = innePantons;            
        });


        $scope.saveArticleData = function (article, success) {

            success = success || function() {};

            $http.post('api/admin/articles/create/', {
                article : article, 
                nazwa_art : article.nazwa_art, 
                koloryPod : article.koloryPod, 
                koloryMie : article.koloryMie, 
                pan : article.pan

            }).success(function (errors){

                    if ( errors) {
                        $scope.errors = errors; 
                        console.log($scope.errors);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.success = true;
                        $scope.article = article;   
                        var articleName = article.nazwa_art;

                        $timeout(function() {
                            $location.path('/drawings/'+ drawingId + '/' + pyNumber +'/' + divOne +'/' + divTwo +'/' + divThree + '/create/article/' + articleName);
                        }, 2000);
                    }


            }).error(function (){
                addedStatus = false;
                console.log('error API');
            });
        }

    }]);
```

The object which I want post must looks like that:

```
    {
    "article": {
        "id_rys": "45",
        "data_art": "15-12-2015",
        "nazwa_art": "fun",
        "pan": {
            "P108": " P108",
            "P109": " P109"
        }
    },
    "nazwa_art": "fun",
    "pan": {
        "P108": " P108",
        "P109": " P109"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a live URL to see it in action?

Comment: It might be that you have an error on your PHP. You can check the console.
If you're not ensuring on the controller what data is to be saved and you encounter an error in your script you might be saving null data or default data.
Error on console.log: 

**<p>Message:  Undefined variable: query</p>**
**<p>Filename: admin/Articles_model.php</p>**
**<p>Line Number: 70</p>**

Comment: I'm corrected the errors and now added new articles (dodaj nowy artykul) works. @Adrián Can you check again?

Comment: I did. Everything seems to work fine, I can't find anything so unusual, inputs should not loose their value, unless you inject new ones. Also, It would be nice to see a var_dump of your PHP script to see what and how is the data being received and handled afterwards.

Comment: It work ok when you not using searching input. Try something like that: add some name in first input text and then in search input write "22" and select the last two checkbox (should be: P221 and PViolet 4022) and then click "dalej". Now should show you table with column: "Lp.","Dodaj Obrazek","Nazwa artykułu", "Kolory w artykule". And in the "Kolory w artykule" should be color which you check but (in my case) are two different - P268 and Black2. And here is the problem. In the table should be the same names of colors which were checked, but is not.

Comment: Can you, instead of actually saving, console.log() the data you are about to save? (do not redirect or send request, just console.log the data object).

Also, separate console.log('text' + Object), it is being printed as Object and not the object itself, for example: console.log('Name new article:'); console.log(article);

Comment: Ok. Now do not redirect or send and display scope of select checkbox (pan) and other data which I send to API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98025/discussion-between-adrian-and-alex-l).